# Powershell for see if a device is in use

Tags: powershell

I need to create a config file where I got variables with either free or occupied

Fx

```
R4353FD3D3=Free
R2323RE445=Occupied
```

I then want to read this in a powershell script. This is to see if any of the the variables (devices) are stated "Free". If it is I can use that device and set it to occupied and save it.

So basiclly this is to see if a device is free for use or not.

Would this be a good aproach or do you guys have a better idea?

Comment: Do you want to test if a _specific_ device is marked Free, do you want to test if _any_ device is marked Free, or do you want to list _all_ device names marked Free?

Comment: I want to check if ANY is free. If free set to Occupied (or busy) and return the name of the variable.

Comment: So if the file has multiple devices with `Free`, you want to only update/return 1 at a time? Or you want to fix _all_ of them at once?

Comment: Only the first one that is free will be returned and it will then be set to occupied in file.